# Approach a function given some points and its maximum

Tags: approximation

For example, I know that a function goes through the points (2.01, 96), (4, 160), (8.1, 257) and (13.1, 321), and that its maximum is 397.

Is it possible to approach the function with this data?

Comment: Is this max between the points given?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide some info about the form of the function.
However you can use a 2nd order taylor polynomial $c-(a-bx)^2$, which has the condition that $c=\max=397$

```
plt = Normal@
   NonlinearModelFit[
    data = {{2.01, 96}, {4, 160}, {8.1, 257}, {13.1, 
       321}}, -(a - b x)^2 + 397, {{a, 15}, b}, x]
Show[Plot[{plt, 397}, {x, -5, 30}, PlotStyle -> Dashed], 
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.2, 0.2, 0.4]]]
```

> `397 - (18.791 - 0.811024 x)^2`

[image]

```
Expand@plt
```

> `43.8992 + 30.4799 x - 0.657761 x^2`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's everything I needed!